# How to compile C file with system call

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

My code contains

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
```

When I used standard gcc, it complains `error: linux/init.h: No such file or directory`.

So what is the correct way to compile this c file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423477/linux-init-h-no-such-file-or-direcotry

Comment: you are mostly compile a kernel module, so you need to prepare your build environment for that

Comment: if I compiled the kernel successfully, what should I do to invoke this c file?

Comment: Are you cross-compiling (compiling for a system other than the one you're building on), or building for the local machine?  If you're cross-compiling, you should set up the toolchain to point to the appropriate kernel headers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running on a Linux box, make sure you have the Linux kernel headers installed, since that file is part of them.

On my system, `apt-get install linux-headers` would do the trick.