# What is the replacement for Linux init.h library

Tags: c, linux

I just started to learn Linux kernel programming, and one of the tutorials use the `linux/init.h` and the `linux/module.h`. and `init.h` holds the `printk` function, but `init.h` does not exists.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h> // source file does not exists

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printk(); // undefined
    return 0;
}
// gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
```

**Is there a replacement for that?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [linux/init.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423477/linux-init-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @TomKarzes No it does not. I already saw it and I have no clue what they are doing

Comment: Why don't you just search for the header that declares it? with an IDE, or grep, or [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/printk)?

Comment: @root Still can't find it in `/usr/include/` and I have no clue how to use Makefile. Please help me if you can.

Comment: It's right there in the link I gave you, `printk.h`. Are you building an out-of-tree module?

Comment: @root I am not sure what `out-of-tree` module means, by I read a little bit about that and I don't think that I'm using `out-of-tree` modules. Also, `#include <linux/printk.h>` doesn't exist.

Comment: You must install headers that are for the same kernel version as the one you're currently running (or compiling for). The QA @TomKarzes linked to contains information how to do it, You should read the comments too. TL;DR `uname -r`, then find package in your package manager of choice with that exact version and install it, then it will just work.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks, but I already tried that, I ran the following command `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, and it says `linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic is already the newest version (5.4.0-42.46)`. But I still can't find `linux/init.h` library.

Comment: @ArlichBachman That last comment was posted by Yamirui, not me.

Comment: @Yamirui Check my comment please